# Is there a way to disable artisan commands?

Tags: laravel, config, laravel-artisan

Is there a way to disable artisan commands from running at all?

For example, if I wanted to disable `php artisan migrate:fresh` from running, where would I go to remove/disable the command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, laravel does not have this feature by default. And this is still under [laravel ideas](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/168).

I also had this problem before and could not find a solution, I am not sure why you want to disable a command. But my case was that in the `production` environment I never want to run `php artisan migrate:fresh`. So what I end up with is to override the default command.

For example, in the `routes/console.php` file:

```php
if ('production' === App::environment()) {
    Artisan::command('migrate:fresh', function () {
        $this->comment('You are not allowed to do this in production!');
    })->describe('Override default command in production.');
}
```

So, when you are in `production`, `php artisan migrate:fresh` will do nothing. You can change the condition based on your requirement, my example is just an idea of how you can override a laravel default command based on some variables in the `.env` file.

You can do a lot of things here as well, I am not sure why you want to disable the command, so this is the best I can help.

Comment: Doesnt artisan already warn if you are trying to run migration while in production?

Comment: @user3532758 "warn" does not mean I can not do it.

Comment: Oh, didnt mean to comment under your answer lol but yeah you are right, it does not mean that.

Comment: @user3532758 also as I said `'production'` is just an example, it may be some other conditions.

Comment: Yeah, but just for conversation's sake, I don't think disabling the command completely would be a good idea. Coz come an actual need, you'd need to play with your code again.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. This is more of a hypothetical rather than actually disabling anything, since I couldn't find anything on this in the Laravel docs.

Answer (score 3):

Create a command like the following

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands\Utils;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Console\Events\CommandStarting;

class PreCommand extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'precommand';

    public function handle(CommandStarting $event) {
        if (app()->environment(['production'])) {
            logger('Trying to fresh database in production');
            if ($event->command == 'migrate:fresh') {
                $this->output = $event->output;
                $this->info('You can not fresh database in the production');
                die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And register it in your EventServiceProvider's boot method

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Console\Commands\Utils\PreCommand;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
use Illuminate\Console\Events\CommandStarting;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{    
    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        Event::listen(CommandStarting::class, PreCommand::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need to arguments and options: `Request::server('argv', null)`