# Disable or overwrite migrate command

Tags: laravel, laravel-modules

Context:
I use this laravel modules package: https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules

I created different modules, and every module does have its migration with its different database connection.

I need to execute all modules migrations but I do not need to execute laravel migration.

What I did is creating a `app:migrate-modules` command that loops the modules and for each modules executes its migrations.

This code:

```
$databaseConnection = config($module->getLowerName().'.database_connection');

if (! empty($databaseConnection)) {
    Artisan::call("module:migrate $module --force --database=$databaseConnection");
}
```

Other than that, I disabled laravel migrate command with this code (I do not want to execute laravel migrate command, cause my project does not have default database connection):

```
Artisan::command('migrate', function () {
    $this->comment('Command NOT AVAILABLE. Use this: php artisan app:migrate-modules');
});
```

My problem is that with this overwrite, also my command does not work, cause package `migrate` command calls laravel `migrate` command.

How can I disable laravel migrate command but still use migrate for all modules?

Comment: in each migration, you can set the `connection('xxx')` isn't [that](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#database-connection-table-options) what you want? you set in `database.php` each of yours database and don't need to overwrite migration commands...

Comment: @francisco it's not what I want, cause in that case I would have the migration table just in the first database, instead I need that every database does have its personal migration table

Comment: you can set multiple connections with same driver(ex: mysql) to different database in the `config`, and don't fuzz the laravel inner code. And Just create a migration for each module, the just call that migration...

Comment: still laravel would create migration table just in the first database, not in each database of all modules

Comment: No, I would have database of module 1 with migration table, and database of module 2 with no migration table (migrations for all modules will be in database of module 1). But I need that both database does have its migration table

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654846/use-one-laravel-migrations-table-per-database) what you want?

Comment: It's exactly what I want, and right now I do it. My problem is that I want to disable migrate laravel command

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63588629/is-there-a-way-to-disable-artisan-commands)